# php array update values if string length is equal to 1

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array like this:

```
array(53) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(2) "11" [3]=> string(1) "7" [4]=> string(2) "11" [5]=> string(1) "7" [6]=> string(2) "10" [7]=> string(2) "10" [8]=> string(1) "9" [9]=> string(1) "8" [10]=> string(1) "8" [11]=> string(2) "12" [12]=> string(1) "6" [13]=> string(2) "10" [14]=> string(2) "10" [15]=> string(2) "12" [16]=> string(1) "2" [17]=> string(1) "3" [18]=> string(1) "8" [19]=> string(1) "5" [20]=> string(1) "4" [21]=> string(1) "3" [22]=> string(1) "2" [23]=> string(1) "2" [24]=> string(1) "3" [25]=> string(1) "7" [26]=> string(1) "3" [27]=> string(1) "6" [28]=> string(1) "9" [29]=> string(1) "3" [30]=> string(1) "3" [31]=> string(2) "12" [32]=> string(2) "12" [33]=> string(1) "1" [34]=> string(2) "12" [35]=> string(1) "5" [36]=> string(1) "2" [37]=> string(1) "8" [38]=> string(1) "6" [39]=> string(1) "9" [40]=> string(1) "9" [41]=> string(2) "10" [42]=> string(1) "1" [43]=> string(1) "2" [44]=> string(1) "3" [45]=> string(2) "10" [46]=> string(1) "7" [47]=> string(1) "4" [48]=> string(2) "11" [49]=> string(2) "12" [50]=> string(1) "1" [51]=> string(1) "9" [52]=> string(1) "9" }
```

I want to every value in this array to have two character length, if array value is:9 to change to 09.

With this I can`t achieve... somewhere I missed something

```
foreach ($outMonth as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($outMonth[$value]) == 1 ) {
        $outMonth[$value] = "0".$value;
        //echo (strlen($outMonth[$value])). "<br>";
    }
}
```

If I dump, I got:

```
array(53) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(2) "01" [2]=> string(2) "11" [3]=> string(2) "03" [4]=> string(2) "11" [5]=> string(2) "05" [6]=> string(2) "10" [7]=> string(2) "10" [8]=> string(2) "08" [9]=> string(2) "09" [10]=> string(3) "010" [11]=> string(2) "12" [12]=> string(3) "012" [13]=> string(2) "10" [14]=> string(2) "10" [15]=> string(2) "12" [16]=> string(1) "2" [17]=> string(1) "3" [18]=> string(1) "8" [19]=> string(1) "5" [20]=> string(1) "4" [21]=> string(1) "3" [22]=> string(1) "2" [23]=> string(1) "2" [24]=> string(1) "3" [25]=> string(1) "7" [26]=> string(1) "3" [27]=> string(1) "6" [28]=> string(1) "9" [29]=> string(1) "3" [30]=> string(1) "3" [31]=> string(2) "12" [32]=> string(2) "12" [33]=> string(1) "1" [34]=> string(2) "12" [35]=> string(1) "5" [36]=> string(1) "2" [37]=> string(1) "8" [38]=> string(1) "6" [39]=> string(1) "9" [40]=> string(1) "9" [41]=> string(2) "10" [42]=> string(1) "1" [43]=> string(1) "2" [44]=> string(1) "3" [45]=> string(2) "10" [46]=> string(1) "7" [47]=> string(1) "4" [48]=> string(2) "11" [49]=> string(2) "12" [50]=> string(1) "1" [51]=> string(1) "9" [52]=> string(1) "9" }
```

You can see that only few values are changed...

Thanks your time!

Comment: It must be `$outMonth[$key] = "0".$value;`

Comment: I tried this version also but if I dump, I got: array(53) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(2) "01" [2]=> string(2) "11" [3]=> string(1) "7" [4]=> string(2) "11" [5]=> string(1) "7" [6]=> string(3) "010" [7]=> string(3) "010" [8]=> s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the key ($outMonth[$key]) for accessing the array element and change the value

```
  foreach ($outMonth as $key => $value) {
      if (strlen($value) === 1 ) {
          $outMonth[$key] = "0".$value;

      }
  }
```

Comment: If I dump, there will be values like this:[7]=> string(3) "010"

Comment: but you have  if( strlen($outMonth[$value]) == 1) and then a value with 2 char don't should be processed .. explain better please

Comment: yes thats the point, I want to only process the values only with one characters

Comment: try usin  === instead of ==

Comment: I got the same values with ===

Comment: are you sure you don't have already '010'  in your array and then this value is not the result for the foreach ..

Comment: before foreach my array dump is: ... [42]=> string(1) "1" [43]=> string(1) "2" [44]=> string(1) "3" [45]=> string(2) "10" [46]=> string(1) "7" [47]=> string(1) "4" [48]=> string(2) "11" [49]=> string(2) "12" [50]=> string(1) "1" [51]=> string(1) "9" [52]=> string(1) "9" }

Comment: with === var_dump: ...  [41]=> string(3) "010" [42]=> string(1) "1" [43]=> string(1) "2" [44]=> string(2) "03" [45]=> string(3) "010" [46]=> string(1) "7" [47]=> string(1) "4" [48]=> string(2) "11" [49]=> string(3) "012" [50]=> string(1) "1" [51]=> string(2) "09" [52]=> string(2) "09" }

Answer (score 1):

You are giving wrong index while updating array value:

```
foreach ($outMonth as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($value) == 1 ) {
        $outMonth[$key] = "0".$value; //<-----------Need to add $key as index
        //echo (strlen($outMonth[$value])). "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: If I dump, there will be values like this:[7]=> string(3) "010"

Comment: Will you show your array? In php format. Not `var_dump`

Comment: What do you mean "in php format" ? I got the results with a:
preg_match_all('#moth (.*?),#',$data,$matchMonth);
$outMonth = $matchMonth[1];

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `str_pad` function, check out the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php). It will left or right pad a string with another string to a given length.

```
foreach ($outMonth as $key => $value) {
    $outMonth[$key] = str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome @almostokey. Please consider marking the reply as an answer if it is useful. Thank you.

Comment: I think I cannot accept more than one answer :D only I can to upvote